# How to get e.g Gimp (snap package) to access printers

Tags: ubuntu, printer, snap-package

Printers are not showing up in the print dialogue in gimp!

Gimp was installed using "snap", e.g.

```
$ sudo snap install gimp
...

$ sudo snap list
Name               Version         Rev   Tracking  Publisher     Notes
...
gimp               2.10.8          101   edge      snapcrafters  -
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things need to be done, update to the --edge version, and make it use cups.

```
$ sudo snap refresh gimp --edge
$ sudo snap connect gimp:cups-control
```

https://github.com/snapcrafters/gimp/issues/22